# Prolog Delay Execution of Text

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am about to write a text based adventure game in Prolog, therefore i have tons of writeline statements. I was wondering if i could slow down the output processing of my text. So imagine the following scenario:

I have a Textblock A that gets printed and i want a 2 sec delay afterwards.
So Textblock B gets printed 2 sec later, without the :- sign in Prolog.

My first idea was to write a loop that compares the current time with currenttime + 2 s but i cant get rid of the :- sign.

Unfortunately; I am a newbie in Prolog and Ii don't have any clue about the thread handling.

That statement might be useful but it doesn't work at all:

```
delayText([H|T]) :-
   put_char(H),
   flush_output,
   sleep(0.1),
   delayText(T).
delayText([]).
```

Neither flush output nor sleep seem to work.

I'm using ProDT in Eclipse.
Thanks in advance, 
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to how you want to realise the writing for your game, but `sleep/1` as used in the example code in your question can be used together with a simple write like so:

```
delayText([]).
delayText([H|T]) :-
   write(H),
   sleep(1),        % Time in seconds
   delayText(T).
```